# JAVA: empty JSON in code, filled JSON in browser

Tags: java, json, http

I'm trying to get a json object from the url:

```
http://www.alfanous.org/jos2?action=search&unit=aya&fuzzy=True&query=حم
```

However, when I run my code with that url, I got an empty json, and when I'm request the url from my browser, the josn is filled.

what is wrong with my code?

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.alfanous.org/jos2?action=search&unit=aya&fuzzy=True&query=حم");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(is);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
    }
```

And I tried also

```
    // Create URL object
    URL obj = new URL("http://www.alfanous.org/jos2?action=search&unit=aya&fuzzy=True&query=حم");

    // Communicate with the URL by HTTP
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    // add request header
     con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

    // Getting response data
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Comment: do you have some error?

Comment: Try to compare the http request (especially the headers) of the browser and your application with a packet sniffer. The server seems to behave differently depending on which application sends the request.

Comment: Try encoding your query parameter value for the url.

Comment: you are correct, that was the problem, JAVA convert the query into some encoding that is not recognized by the server, when I convert it, the server recognized it.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to encode the url string before passing it to the `URL` constructor.

```
String urlstring = "http://www.alfanous.org/jos2?action=search&unit=aya&fuzzy=True&query=حم";
URLEncoder.encode(urlstring, "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL(urlstring);
```

Then continues with the previous code shown in the original post.

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(is);
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
}
```

And the moral is.. I should encode the url before I use it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `BufferedReader` like  this:

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.alfanous.org/jos2?action=search&unit=aya&fuzzy=True&query=حم");
   URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
   BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(thisLine);
     }
```